# Sending order email confirmation using mailchimp

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

Fairly new to mailchimp and nodejs. I'm trying to send an email using mailchimp after a user places order in my website entirely using nodejs. However document states there is no real way to send one-to-one email using mailchimp but only possible to send bulk list of emails. How would I achieve this using nodejs? I've installed mailchimp package and ready to go with API key. I need a function that sends email to every user upon completing an order with a template.

Answer (score 0):

I think that MailChimp is a bulk email sender. 
If you want to do one-to-one email, then you should try Mailgun from Mailchimp.

A popular alternative is Sendgrid and they have a good, easy-to-use NPM package.